# Firebase callable function to read real time database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Here I am trying to access the user's data from real time database by providing the UID. I have tried so many things but none worked. I have followed the documentation but no luck I am keep getting error -

[Sending back results [promise]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result)

Another [example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/bf60dc92e25f15b22167d90782ccf6bb408c6e36/functions/functions/index.js#L87-L96) for writing the data which I have followed to create my logic but it didn't worked -

```
exports.userData = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    // verify Firebase Auth ID token
    if (!context.auth) {
        return { message: 'Authentication Required!', code: 401 };
    }

    const userId = data.text;
    const ref = database.ref('/USERS/' + userId);
    return ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
            console.log(snapshot); /* <--- I have tried with this and without this none worked*/
        })
        .then(snapshot => {
            return {
                data: snapshot
            };
        }).catch((error) => {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message, error);
        });
});
```

The error I get on client side is -

```
service.ts:160 POST https://us-central1-gokuapp.cloudfunctions.net/userData 500
error.ts:66 Uncaught (in promise) Error: INTERNAL
    at new YN (error.ts:66)
    at XN (error.ts:175)
    at rC.<anonymous> (service.ts:231)
    at tslib.es6.js:100
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
    at r (tslib.es6.js:71)
```

**Edit:**  Before, I was correctly writing the code on my end but, I was either getting the error or null object based on the changes that I made during the discovery process. Anyone who had faced the same problem, just remember this... "cloud functions takes time to **warm up** to get fully functional", even though I am really thankful to @Frank van Puffelen and @oug Stevenson for their input. :) :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `on()` in Cloud Functions, since that attaches a persistent listener to a query (and it doesn't return a promise).  Use `once()` instead to query data a single time and get a promise the resolves with a snapshot.  Also you should use `snapshot.val()` to get a plain JavaScript object with the contents of the snapshot.

```js
return ref.once('value')   // use once() here
    .then(snapshot => {
        return {
            data: snapshot.val()   // also use val() here to get a JS object
        };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message, error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Callable Cloud Functions can return any JSON data. Your `snapshot` variable is a `DataSnapshot` object however, which contains a lot more than just JSON data.

You're probably looking to return the snapshot's value:

```
.then(snapshot => {
    return {
        data: snapshot.val()
    };
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I have tried that before but still same error.

Comment: Doug pointed out another problem too. You might have to do his first, but then this is definitely another problem.